# Close parent popup from child popup

Tags: asp.net, telerik, popup

I am using telrik radopen function to open the popups. I have a situation in which child popup opens from parent popup which opens from grandparent .aspx page.

> Grandparent (.aspx page) -> popup (parent) -> popup(child)

I want to close the parent popup and child popup on click of a button on child popup. I tried using

```
GetRadWindow().BrowserWindow.BrowserWindow.Close() // this one and variations of this errored !

GetRadWindow().BrowserWindow.close(); // this didn't error but didn't close parent window

GetRadWindow().Close(); //this closes only child window when invoked from button click on //child window
```

I read the question Is it possible to close parent window from child (Javascript)?

If in case it is not possible to close the parent popup from child popup is there a workaround so that I can simulate the behavior of 'submit button click' on child control can close child and parent popup and refresh the grid on the grandparent .aspx page?

May be redirect can help. In that case how do I do that?
Any suggestions.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of closing all Windows a one shot, you can close Child Window first, then close the Parent Windows (based on the value passed by the Child Window).

[Window / Returning Values from a Dialog](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/window/examples/dialogreturnvalue/defaultcs.aspx)

[CommunicationBetweenRadWindowsASPNET.zip](http://www.telerik.com/ClientsFiles/088130_CommunicationBetweenRadWindowsASPNET.zip)